# Accessing and updating ReturnUrl variable (vb.net / C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have implemented custom navigation in a web app and with every click that points to another web page within the web app I am updating the URL using Javascript's (window.history.pushState). The page content is updated by using custom callbacks. Essentially there is only one page and part of this page is updated using callbacks.

When the session or cookie expires and the user is logged out the ReturnUrl variable of the FormsAuthentication (vb.net/c#) points to the 1st URL that the user logged in to. My question is: How can I access and update the ReturnUrl variable (in the code behind) with every callback so, the ReturnUrl variable in the URL will be correct after the user gets logged out?

Comment: Since the javascript is running on the client and the vb.net is running on the server you would have to have javascript put the value in a hiddenvalue control or maybe a cookie so you can access it from the code behind.

Comment: @KenTucker, I plan to use the default FormsAuthentication "ReturnUrl" variable (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when the user gets logged out. This is because, when the session is lost, I cannot access the session (there is no session) or any of the server variables. The cookie might be a good idea if I won't be able to access the ReturnUrl variable.